# sending string in client-server programming in C language

Tags: c, sockets

I'm currently doing socket programming. Now, bytes can be easily sent and received between client-server.
Now, I want to send string between client server.

The code which I've used for the same is(Client):

```
    strcpy(recvbuf, sendbuf);
    send(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, strlen(recvbuf), 0);
    printf("\nSending string...");
```

(Server)

```
    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf) -1, 0);
    recvbuf[iResult]= '\0';
    strcpy(sendbuf2, recvbuf);
    printf("String recieved = %s", sendbuf2);
```

But, it is not showing the correct result.
Is there any link which can help me?

Comment: What is the `printf` in the server code printing? What do you expect?

Comment: what is the function you are using for scanning? is it scanf, fgets or what? and what is printf printing? what are you expecting as @anish asked?

Comment: How have you defined `recvbuf`, is it `char recvbuf[NNN];` or `char *recvbuf`?

Comment: When you say, _"bytes can be easily sent and received"_, how are you verifying that they are sent and received correctly? This code cannot do that accurately.

Answer (score 0):

First of all string is also bytes. As long as you can easily send/receive bytes, in same way you send/receive string.

Some more hint. You should be aware of TCP or UDP you are using. With UDP, each send() sends a packet, recv() receives a packet once. But with tcp is a byte stream. That means send() just writes some bytes to the stream, and you cannot expect how many bytes a recv() will actually receive until it returns. You have to design a mechanism to decode packet from byte stream. Say your case, you may use '\0' to split string packet.

Answer (score 0):

```
recvbuf[iResult]= '\0';
```

could be very wrong, because iResult could be -1 and you would be writing before your array begins, so you would be corrupting memory.

Apart from that, without more detail I can't know.

Answer (score 0):

I think that recv() is misused.

1. Need to check return value of recv(). If return code is negative, you should not progress rest of lines.
2. To get a positive value of recv(), you should set flag (last argument). '0' means that receive all bytes of length you put "sizeof(recvbuf) -1". So that code is never returned until all 1023 bytes are received.
3. Determine that how many bytes in a socket and read exact length of bytes.

Try this...

```
int length_to_read = 0;

length_to_read = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf) -1, MSG_PEEK);
if( length_to_read < 0 ) {
  // error
  return;
}

iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, length_to_read, 0);
if( iResult < 0 ) {
  // error
  return;
}
```

PS. Above codes is redundant recv() system call. In general TCP/IP socket programming, you should know the exact length of data. For example, first 4 bytes for length and trailing data. Why don't you define length for c/s interface?

Step 1. calculate size of data.
Step 2. Send length and data.

Step 1. read 4 byte for length.
Step 2. read data exact length previous calculated length.

Comment: None of this is relevant to the question though I agree with you. This is not the OP's problem.